# Writing faster than reading from a socket

Tags: java, sockets, networking, tcp, buffer

I did an experiment and I created a program with 2 threads: a server thread and a client thread.
The server thread accepts a connection from the client, does a long process (emulated by `sleep()`), and prints the result.

The client on the other hand sends messages really fast.

See the code:

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class SocketTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread serverThread = new Thread(() -> server());
        Thread clientThread = new Thread(() -> client());

        serverThread.start();
        clientThread.start();

        serverThread.join();
        clientThread.join();
    }

    private static void server() {
        try (
            ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket( 1234 );
            Socket client = listener.accept()){  // wait for connection

            while (true) {
                InputStream in = client.getInputStream();

                // read a newline or carriage-return-delimited string
                BufferedReader bin =
                        new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( in ) );
                String someString = bin.readLine();
                //process
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                System.out.println(someString);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void client () {
        try (Socket server = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 1234))
        {
            while (true) {
                OutputStream out = server.getOutputStream();

                // write a newline or carriage return delimited string
                PrintWriter pout = new PrintWriter(out, true);
                pout.println("Hello!");

                // send the the string
                pout.flush();
            }
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When I ran the program I got the following output:

```
Hello!
Hello!
llo!
o!

ello!
lo!
!
Hello!
llo!
o!

ello!
lo!
!
Hello!
llo!
o!

ello!
lo!
!
Hello!
llo!
o!

ello!
...
```

Now I am not sure I understand it 100%...
But I did run the experiment of using an input the size of a power of 2 (including `/n`) and the output was not cut off.

Can someone explain to me:

1. What's going on internally?
2. Why no error is thrown?
3. What would you do to overcome this problem?

Thanks!!

Comment: Do you know why `BufferedReader` is called that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private static void server() {
    ...
        while (true) {
            InputStream in = client.getInputStream();

            // read a newline or carriage-return-delimited string
            BufferedReader bin =
                    new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( in ) );
            String someString = bin.readLine();
```

This creates a new `BufferedReader` for each run of while loop. But `readline` will not only read a line from the socket. It will instead read a larger amount of data, check if there is a line end in it, read more if no line end yet etc and finally return the line. The rest of the read data is kept in the `BufferedReader`. By implicitly abandoning the `BufferedReader` at the end of loop run and creating a new one at the beginning of a new loop run you abandon all data in the buffer which were already read from the socket.

Instead you should create your `BufferedReader` outside the loop and use it there so that no data gets abandoned:

```
private static void server() {
    ...
        InputStream in = client.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader bin =
                new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( in ) );

        while (true) {
            // read a newline or carriage-return-delimited string
            String someString = bin.readLine();
```

Comment: How did I miss that?
The real point of my experiment is to see what is happening when you write faster than you read to a socket. Since I am not seeing error now I am assuming that TCP takes care of resending the message as expected

Comment: @whomaniac: *"... I am assuming that TCP takes care of resending the message as expected"* - There is no resending. If the recipient cannot keep up reading data the sender will slow down sending which ultimately in your code means that some `pout.println` will block for a while. See [tcp flow control](https://www.google.com/search?q=tcp+flow+control) for details.